# How to pass an array from controller to library in php(codeigniter framework)

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to I pass an array from controller to an library .Assume Controller name is control.php
and library name is lib.php and the function name where I want to receive the array is rectest(). Let's assume the array name I want to pass is $arr1 .

Comment: Check the question now guys. Is it now clear enough for you . Now can you give me a correct solution Or is there something else you want to   know about.

Comment: `class Control extends CI_Controller {
 public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  
  $this->lib->rectest($arr1);
 }
}`

Comment: @Michael D. Yup dude I have done it the same way.In the lib I have done something like this  lib($arr1=NULL){ $data= $arr1[0]; echo $data;} .But it does not work.What I am doing is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say your library name is Fun.php and $args is the set of arguments you wish to pass.

You could pass arguments on library initialization as follows:

```
$this->load->library('Fun',$args);
```

And from you library constructor you could access it

```
class Fun{
  public function __construct($args=array()){
         print_r($args); //print you arguments and do as
  }

}
```

Comment: In library Fun i have a function called getvalue() I want the $args in getvalue() function

Comment: you could assign those args in a class variable if you like